# Add attributes in Networkx write_graphml before opening in Gephi

Tags: python, pandas, networkx, gephi, graphml

I have a dataframe consisting of possible network connections in the format `df = pd.DataFrame(["A", "B", "Count", "some_attribute"])`. This dataframe represents connections like this:

- A has a connection with B
- This connection occurred "Count" times
- This connection has a specific attribute (i.e. a specific type of contact)

I want to export this Dataframe to the graphml format. It works fine using the following code:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_weighted_edges_from(df[["A", "B", "Count"]].values)
nx.write_graphml(G, "my_graph.graphml")
```

This code results in a graphml file with the correct graph, which I can use with Gephi. Now I want to add an attribute:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_weighted_edges_from(df[["A", "B", "Count"]].values, attr=df["some_attribute"].values)
nx.write_graphml(G, "my_graph.graphml")
```

Whenever I try to add attributes in this code, it becomes impossible to write it to a graphml file. With this code, I get the following error message:

```
NetworkXError: GraphML writer does not support <class 'numpy.ndarray'> as data values.
```

I found related articles (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099194/python-networkx-cant-export-to-graphml-with-attributes) one), but it didn't provide any solution for this problem. Does anyone have a solution for adding attributes to a graphml file using networkx so I can use them in Gephi?

Comment: doesn't `attr=df["some_attribute"]` work?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It will give the same error, except that numpy is replaced by Series.

Comment: It appears that 'some_attribute' is a field with type numpy.ndarray which is not a known graphml type.  Is it an array or a single number?  If it is a single number you could try to convert it to an integer or float first.  Those types are both useable in graphml.

Comment: reshaping the data is probably your best bet, and/or serializing to string & deserializing if it's really supposed to be a list and not a simple type (you could try pickle or yaml if you want reconstitution, or json/msgpack should always work).

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: Guido - I assume you're question was to @CorleyBrigman  (if you don't include the name like I just did and it's not the person asking the question, he/she won't get any notices)

Comment: networks doesn't support lists as attributes. As @Kevin said (and I upvoted)  `add_weighted_edges_from` assigns the same attributes to all edges; it doesn't unroll it. You could use `add_edges_from`, it takes a list of `(u, v, d)` where `d` is the attribute dictionary for that edge only. So you'd need something like `add_edges_from([(u,v,{'weight': w, 'attr': a}) for u,v,w,a in df[['A', 'B', 'Count', 'some_attribute']] ])` (did not check code but it should be something like that)

Comment: Thanks @CorleyBrigman -- just need `.values` -- edited the answer to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: As a sidenote: what also helped for me was to not encode the columns as UTF-8 strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the random DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,1,2,0,0],
                   'B': [1,2,3,2,3],
                   'Count': [1,2,5,1,1],
                   'some_attribute': ['red','blue','red','blue','red']})

    A   B   Count  some_attribute
0   0   1   1   red
1   1   2   2   blue
2   2   3   5   red
3   0   2   1   blue
4   0   3   1   red
```

Following the code from above to instantiate a `Graph`:

```
import networkx as nx    
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_weighted_edges_from(df[["A","B", "Count"]].values, attr=df["some_attribute"].values)
```

when inspecting an edge, it appears that the `numpy` array, `df['some_attribute'].values`, gets assigned as an attribute to each edge:

```
print (G.edge[0][1])
print (G.edge[2][3])
{'attr': array(['red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue', 'red'], dtype=object), 'weight': 1}
{'attr': array(['red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue', 'red'], dtype=object), 'weight': 5}
```

If I understand your intent correctly, I'm assuming you want each edge's attribute to correspond to the `df['some_attribute']` column.

You may find it easier to create your `Graph` using [`nx.from_pandas_dataframe()`](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_dataframe.html), especially since you already have data formatted in a `DataFrame` object.

```
G = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df, 'A', 'B', ['Count', 'some_attribute'])

print (G.edge[0][1])
print (G.edge[2][3])
{'Count': 1, 'some_attribute': 'red'}
{'Count': 5, 'some_attribute': 'red'}
```

writing to file was no problem:

```
nx.write_graphml(G,"my_graph.graphml")
```

except, I'm not a regular Gephi user so there may be another way to solve the following.  When I loaded the file with `'Count'` as the edge attribute, the Gephi graph didn't recognize edge weights by default.  So I changed the column name from `'Count'` to `'weight'` and saw the following when I loaded into Gephi:

```
df.columns=['A', 'B', 'weight', 'some_attribute']
G = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df, 'A', 'B', ['weight', 'some_attribute'])
nx.write_graphml(G,"my_graph.graphml")
```

[image]

Hope this helps and that I understood your question correctly.

### Edit

Per Corley's comment above, you can use the following if you choose to use `add_edges_from`.

```
G.add_edges_from([(u,v,{'weight': w, 'attr': a}) for u,v,w,a in df[['A', 'B', 'Count', 'some_attribute']].values ])
```

There is no significant performance gain, however I find `from_pandas_dataframe` more readable.

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.arange(0,1000000),
                   'B': np.arange(1,1000001),
                   'Count': np.random.choice(range(10), 1000000, replace=True),
                   'some_attribute': np.random.choice(['red','blue'], 1000000, replace=True,)})

%%timeit
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(u,v,{'weight': w, 'attr': a}) for u,v,w,a in df[['A', 'B', 'Count', 'some_attribute']].values ])

1 loop, best of 3: 4.23 s per loop

%%timeit
G = nx.Graph()
G = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df, 'A', 'B', ['Count', 'some_attribute'])

1 loop, best of 3: 3.93 s per loop
```

Comment: btw, i missed the `from_pandas_dataframe` the first time... that is a very nice feature I'll have to remember...

Comment: This answer helped me to solve the issue, thanks a lot!